# ¿Cargar componentes de manera asincrona?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, axios

quisiera saber de que manera puedo cargar los componentes de manera asincrona en vuejs usando axios, tengo varias paginas, pero el problema es que estoy cargando diferentes tipos de informacion mediante axios y al navegar por las diferentes paginas estoy experimentando unos micro retrasos debido a que aun no se han terminado de cargar los datos o informacion que estoy consultando mediante axios hacia una api rest.

Comment: ¿No te ayudará que el componente muestre un icono de cargando o algo así mientras se carguen los datos de dicho componente?

Comment: @ManueldelaCruz No amigo, para este caso en especifico necesito que el componente se muestre solo una vez todos los datos hayan sido cargados :(

Answer (score 1):

Para que tu componente se cargue correcta mente usa una variable para mostrar tu componente una vez que los datos lleguen de la llamada a la api ejemplo:

Usa el método then() de las promesas en javascript, este método se ejecuta luego de que la petición a la api es devuelta, justo ahí es donde puedes cambiar la variable showComponent para que muestre el componente que quieres mostrar.

```js
Vue.component('comp-mostrar', {
    template: `
        <div>
            Este es el componente que se muestra depués de la llamada asincrona a la api
        </div>
    `
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    
    data(){
      return {
        showComponent: false,//Muestra al componente que se quiere cargar
        showLoading: false,//Muestra el mensaje de Cargando...
      }
    },

    methods: {
      getData(){

          this.showLoading = true;

          axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api/').then(res =>{
            if (res.data){
                console.log(res.data);
                this.showLoading = false;
                this.showComponent = true;
                //Más código
            }
          }).catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
          });
      },
    },
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div id="app" class="container">
        
        <button 
            @click="getData"
            class="btn btn-primary"
        >
            Consultar datos        
        </button>

        <!--El componente que quieres mostrar después de la llamada a la api-->
        <comp-mostrar v-if="showComponent">

        </comp-mostrar>

        <h2 v-if="showLoading">Cargando...</h2>
    </div>

    

    <!--Vue js-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js" integrity="sha256-chlNFSVx3TdcQ2Xlw7SvnbLAavAQLO0Y/LBiWX04viY=" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <!--axios-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha256-S1J4GVHHDMiirir9qsXWc8ZWw74PHHafpsHp5PXtjTs=" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tu tiempo amigo, lo que sucede con ese componente que quiero cargar es que hace 4 llamadas a diferentes apis para obtener ciertos datos y generar unos graficos, el problema es que no todas las llamadas terminan al mismo tiempo, generando así como un tipo de lag o retraso cuando cambias de una pagina a otra, lo que no he logrado saber es si en vue hay forma de mostrar el componente únicamente cuando todas las llamadas a las apis hayan terminado

Comment: Entonces se me ocurre que hagas llamadas a las apis una seguida de la otra, es decir cuando el .then() devuelva los datos ahí haces el llamado a otra api y así con las demás apis y en la ultima llamada cargas el componente que quieres.